# How can I run android in bundle for Nativescript

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-angular

When I followed the steps to migrate a web project to code sharing using angular, after doing tns run android --bundle, I got the following error:

```
ERROR in Could not resolve module C:\Ideas\Source\b2bAngular\src\app.module
```

Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
Webpack build done!
Executing before-shouldPrepare hook from C:\Ideas\Source\b2bAngular\hooks\before-shouldPrepare\nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Executing before-cleanApp hook from C:\Ideas\Source\b2bAngular\hooks\before-cleanApp\nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Preparing project...
Executing before-prepareJSApp hook from C:\Ideas\Source\b2bAngular\hooks\before-prepareJSApp\nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Gradle clean...
         + setting applicationId
         + applying user-defined configuration from C:\Ideas\Source\b2bAngular\App_Resources\Android\app.gradle
         + adding nativescript runtime package dependency: nativescript-optimized-with-inspector
         + adding aar plugin dependency: C:\Ideas\Source\b2bAngular\node_modules\tns-core-modules-widgets\platforms\android\widgets-release.aar

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.

  > Unable to delete directory: C:\Ideas\Source\b2bAngular\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug\app\app\cars\model
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Unable to apply changes on device: c1f7d849. Error is: Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1.
Executing after-watch hook from C:\Ideas\Source\b2bAngular\hooks\after-watch\nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Stopping webpack watch
Executing after-watch hook from C:\Ideas\Source\b2bAngular\hooks\after-watch\nativescript-dev-webpack.js

Any help is really appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked when I started the process again, but this time I didn't execute the  update-ns-webpack script, and it worked.

So I started a new project executing that script and it didn't work, but when I created a new project without executing it, everything worked perfect.

I think is something with that script